# customize columns of a datagridview whose datasource is from linq

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

I have a library function that returns a list of domain objects from a Linq query.

```
IList<Apple> getApplesByCriteria( ... );
```

I bind the DataSource property of a DataGridView to the result of this function.  Everything works well.  Now I want to manipulate properties of Apple.  The presentation domain object (UIApple) is different than the original domain object (Apple), where

```
UIApple map( Apple apple );
```

converts one to the other.

If I create an intermediate class - UIApple, what do I need to do to persist editing of the DataGridView back to the database?  I learned that adding `[Browsable(false)]` can hide a collumn.  However, I'd prefer not to 1) pollute the domain objects with UI concepts; 2) change the auto generated source code.

Comment: Is this Linq-To-SQL?  EF(35 or 4)? Or something different?

Comment: I do not think you can have both of these with linq to sql.  But hopefully someone will prove me wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created UIApple which is backed by Apple and contains all the manipulation code.

For example:

```
class Apple {
    // generated by Visual Studio
    public int Color { ...
}

class UIApple {
    private Apple _domain;
    public string Color 
    {
         get { if(_domain.Color == 0) return "Black"; }
         set { if(value == "Black") _domain.Color = 0; }
    }
    // hide all unwanted attributes        
}
```

To persist at the end of editing,

```
UIApple uiApple;

// some editing through UI

// to commit -
db.SubmitChanges();
```